# How do i get the value in an anchor tag?

Tags: html, angular

For getting value in input tag we can use `<id>`.value like

```
<input type="text" #solutionInput (keyup)="0"><br>
<solutionDetail [solutionName]="solutionInput.value" > </solutionDetail>
```

where 'solutionInput' is `<id>` here.

For an anchor tag, how can we get the value "CEP" as in below?

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1"> CEP </a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" #link> CEP </a>
```

the you can access it with

```
link.innerText
```

Comment: Thank You. That really helped!!

Comment: I want to get value in form field through anchor tag, but got this error.Screenshot-https://prnt.sc/wdzxq8, https://prnt.sc/we07wk.Here is code <form method="POST" id="form_display" >
 <label>Name</label>
 <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['upd']; ?>" /> </form>